# React Native App - Google SignIn

Tags: android, firebase, react-native, firebase-authentication, google-signin

[SOLVED] - how can I make a 'Sign In with Google' button with firebase?

I created my firebase account, activated authentication with Google, and followed the steps that were there. Now, how can I implement it in my code?

Sorry if I was not clear enough or something is wrong, English isn't my first language.

Can any of you guys help me?

[image: enter image description hlçlçere]

Answer (score 1):

Google SignIn is one of the lightest in authentication mode of Firebase. Please review this official firebase [documentation with sample code](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-login-demo-android) for google signin

Answer (score 0):

[this](https://github.com/firebase/quickstart-android/tree/master/auth) firebase official insight into authentication types shows step by step direction towards all types of logins. Hope it helps, becuase i succedded

Comment: it is the same which I have answered tho

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the type of application  Android, Web or iOS. The easy way to start is FirebaseUI, A firebase supporting the project.

Here is the link, https://github.com/firebase/FirebaseUI